# Not all data shows when displaying table in MySQLi

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to switch from MySQL to MySQLi.

If you go to my working page here:
[Your Favorite Movie](http://bretleduc.com/FavMov/)
click List Movies and scroll down, you'll see that there is data in all the fields going across.

But if you go to:
[Your Favorite Movie (MySQLi)](http://bretleduc.com/FavMov/indexm.php)
click List Movies, you will see that only the ID and Date and Time fields are populated.

Am I missing something in the code?

Here is the relevant code for the MySQLi page:

```
if ($choice == 'list movies') {
$query = "SELECT movie_id, movie_name, name, comment, date FROM movie";

if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, $query)) {

/* execute statement */
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

/* bind result variables */
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $movie_id, $movie_name, $nname, $ccomment, $date);

echo "<table border=1><tr><th>ID</th><th>Movie Name</th><th>Submitter Name</th><th>Comment</th><th>Date and Time</th></tr>";

/* fetch values */
while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {

    if ($movie_name == '') $movie_name = '&nbsp;';
    if ($nname == '') $nname = '&nbsp;';
    if ($ccomment == '') $ccomment = '&nbsp;';

    echo "<tr><td>$movie_id</td><td>$movie_name</td><td>$nname</td><td>$ccomment</td><td>$date</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

}

/* close statement */
mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);

/* close connection */
mysqli_close($con);
}
```

UPDATE 9:39am on 1/26/15:
This is the code from http://bretleduc.com/FavMov (in its entirety) which works:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Your Favorite Movie</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
<h1> Your Favorite Movie </h1>
<br>
This webpage simply records the names of your favorite movies.  I created it to practice PHP and MySQL coding.
<br><br>

<p style="text-align:center"><a href="http://bretleduc.com">Return to BretLeduc.com</a></p>

<br><br>
<?php

// connect to the Database
include('connect.php');

$id = $_POST['id'];
$moviename = $_POST['moviename'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$comment = $_POST['comment'];
$choice = $_POST['submit'];
$id_mysql = mysql_real_escape_string($id);
$movie_mysql = mysql_real_escape_string($moviename);
$name_mysql = mysql_real_escape_string($name);
$comment_mysql = mysql_real_escape_string($comment);

//list movies
if ($choice == 'list movies') { 
$sql = "select * from movie";
echo "<br />" . $sql . "<br />";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
echo "<table border=1><tr><th>ID</th><th>Movie Name</th><th>Submitter Name</th><th>Comment</th><th>Date and Time</th></tr>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

if ($row['movie_name'] == '') $row['movie_name'] = '&nbsp;';
if ($row['name'] == '') $row['name'] = '&nbsp;';
if ($row['comment'] == '') $row['comment'] = '&nbsp;';

$mn = nl2br($row['movie_name']);
$n = nl2br($row['name']);
$c = nl2br($row['comment']);

echo "<tr><td>{$row['movie_id']}</td><td>$mn</td><td>$n</td><td>$c</td><td>{$row['date']}</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
}

// add a movie
if ($choice == 'add movie') {
$sql="INSERT INTO movie (movie_id, movie_name, name, comment, date)
VALUES (null, '$movie_mysql', '$name_mysql', '$comment_mysql', NOW());";
echo "<br />".$sql."<br />";
$r = mysql_query ($sql); 
if ($r) echo "<br />Insert succeeded<br />";
else
echo "<br />Insert failed <br /> MySQL Error Number: " . mysql_errno($r) . ": " . mysql_error($r). "<br />";
}

//delete a movie
if ($choice == 'delete movie') { 
$q = "delete from movie where movie_id = '$id_mysql'";
echo "<br />".$q."<br />";
$r = mysql_query($q);
if (mysql_affected_rows() > 0 ) echo "<br />delete succeeded<br>";
else
echo "<br />Delete failed <br /> MySQL Error Number: " . mysql_errno() . ": " . mysql_error(). "<br />";
}


?>

<br />
<form action="" method="post"/>
What is the name of your favorite movie? <textarea name="moviename" rows="1" cols="20"></textarea><br />
What is your name? <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name ?>"/><br />
Comment: <textarea name="comment" rows="1" cols="20"></textarea><br />  
<br /> <br />
If you would like to delete an entry, enter its ID here and press "delete movie": <input name="id" type="text"/><br />
<br /> <br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="list movies"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="add movie"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="refresh"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="delete movie"/>
</form>
<br />
<br />
<br />
<p style="text-align:center"><a href="http://bretleduc.com">Return to BretLeduc.com</a></p>
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the code from http://bretleduc.com/FavMov/indexm.php (in its entirety) which does not work:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Your Favorite Movie</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
<h1> Your Favorite Movie </h1>
<br>
This webpage simply records the names of your favorite movies.  I created it to practice PHP and MySQL coding.

<br><br>

<p style="text-align:center"><a href="http://bretleduc.com">Return to BretLeduc.com</a></p>

<br><br>

<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');

// connect to the Database
include('mysql_connect(powweb).php');

date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');

$con=mysqli_connect("host","username","password","database");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
echo "<br />Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error() . "<br />";
}

$id = $_POST['id'];
$moviename = $_POST['moviename'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$comment = $_POST['comment'];
$choice = $_POST['submit'];

// escape variables for security

$id_mysqli = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $id);
$movie_mysqli = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $moviename);
$name_mysqli = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $name);
$comment_mysqli = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $comment);

//list movies

if ($choice == 'list movies') {
$query = "SELECT movie_id, movie_name, name, comment, date FROM movie";

if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, $query)) {

/* execute statement */
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

/* bind result variables */
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $movie_id, $movie_name, $nname, $ccomment, $date);

echo "<table border=1><tr><th>ID</th><th>Movie Name</th><th>Submitter Name</th><th>Comment</th><th>Date and Time</th></tr>";

/* fetch values */
while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {

if ($movie_name == '') $movie_name = '&nbsp;';
if ($nname == '') $nname = '&nbsp;';
if ($ccomment == '') $ccomment = '&nbsp;';

echo "<tr><td>$movie_id</td><td>$movie_name</td><td>$nname</td><td>$ccomment</td><td>$date</td></tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
}

/* close statement */
mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);

/* close connection */
mysqli_close($con);
}

// add a movie
if ($choice == 'add movie') {
$sql="INSERT INTO movie (movie_id, movie_name, name, comment, date)
VALUES (null, '$movie_mysqli', '$name_mysqli', '$comment_mysqli', NOW());";
echo "<br />" . $sql . "<br />";
if (!mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {
die("<br />Insert failed <br /> MySQL Error Number: " . mysql_errno($con) . ": " . mysql_error($con). "<br />");
}
echo "<br />Insert succeeded<br />";
mysqli_close($con);
}

//delete a movie
if ($choice == 'delete movie') { 
$q = "delete from movie where movie_id = '$id_mysqli'";
echo "<br />" . $q . "<br />";
$r = mysqli_query($con, $q);
if (mysqli_affected_rows($con) > 0 ) echo "<br />Delete succeeded<br />";
else
echo "<br />Delete failed <br />";
}

?>

<br />
<form action="" method="post"/>
<br />

What is the name of your favorite movie? <textarea name="moviename" rows="1" cols="20"></textarea><br />
What is your name? <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name ?>"/><br />
Comment: <textarea name="comment" rows="1" cols="20"></textarea><br />  
<br /> <br />
If you would like to delete an entry, enter its ID here and press "delete movie": <input name="id" type="text"/><br />
<br /> <br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="list movies"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="add movie"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="refresh"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="delete movie"/>
</form>
<br />
<br />
<br />
<p style="text-align:center"><a href="http://bretleduc.com">Return to BretLeduc.com</a></p>
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
</body>
</html>
```

I think it should be pointed out that, in this indexm.php page, the process where I check to see if $movie_name, $nname and $ccomment are empty and then assign `&nbsp;` to them, works correctly and the table draws a border around those empty cells.  This would seem to imply that the webpage is receiving the data from the database for those variables as empty (blank).  When I comment out that process, the empty cells do not have borders around them.

I also added:
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`
`mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`
to the code as Fred requested.

Comment: can't see anything obviously wrong with the code. How is THIS code different from the page that does work?

Comment: @MarcB Why is OP preparing when there's nothing to prepare? I.e. `if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, "SELECT District FROM City WHERE Name=?")) {` or is that still valid?

Comment: @Fred-ii-: gotta prepare something if you want to use bound parameters while fetching. you can prepare something with NO placeholders. it's kinda wasteful, but  not wrong.

Comment: @MarcB Oh, ok; fair enough.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything and `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT)`

Comment: Plus check to see if you did set your POST variables. I.e.: `$movie=$_POST['movie'];` etc. showing us more code may help. This part is unclear `if ($choice == 'list movies')` and whatever's above that.

Comment: I don't see any error messages being displayed on the indexm.php page.  I also see that no errors are being generated in the web host's error log.